# Can't theme programs in Qtile

Tags: window-manager, qt, window-management, gtk3

I followed this guide:
`https://github.com/antoniosarosi/dotfiles`.
Programs like Thunar, Firefox, and qbittorent don't seem to follow the theme. I installed lxappearance, kvantum, and qt5ct and tried them all. I edited gtkrc-2.0 and put

```
gtk-theme-name="Material-Black-Blueberry-4.0" 
gtk-icon-theme-name="Blueberry-Numix-2021"
```

I edited ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini with the same. Also my ~/.profile

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
export GTK2_RC_FILES="$HOME/.gtkrc-2.0"
```

and my /etc/environment

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
```

Specs if they matter:

```
OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64
Kernel: 5.15.65-1-MANJARO
Uptime: 20 hours, 58 mins
Packages: 997 (pacman)
Shell: bash 5.1.16
Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080
WM: Qtile
Theme: Material-Black-Blueberry-4.0 [GTK2/3]
Icons: Blueberry-Numix-2021 [GTK2/3]
Terminal: alacritty
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X (16) @ 3.600GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
Memory: 3618MiB / 15905MiB
```

Answer (score 0):

~/.bash_profile

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"
```